# Can anyone help me to get the solution of this first order ODE?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

$\ y'(x)=-\sqrt(y(x)^3)$ with initial condition $\ y(0)=-2$.

In fact, this is an example [here](http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica/AdvancedNumericalDifferentialEquationSolvingInMathematica.pdf) in page 3-4

```
NDSolve[{y'[x] == -Sqrt[y[x]^3], y[0] == -2}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

then plot it

```
Plot[Evaluate[Part[Re[y[x] /. %], {1, 2, 4}]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But I can not get the curves, MMA gives me a mass of error.

Comment: it seems a typo in the pdf. The ODE is there few lines above it. it is `NDSolve[{y'[x]^2-y[x]^3==0,y[0]^2==4},y,{x,1}]`

Comment: Hi, @Nasser. I don't think it is a typo. Because your equation have avoid the branch cut problem :)

Comment: You can always try `DSolve` since it can actually solve it analytically . screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9MRUo.png)  `eq = y'[x] == -Sqrt[y[x]^3];
ic = y[0] == -2;
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[{eq, ic}, y[x], x]; Plot[Re[sol], {x, 0, 1}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is there is no solution.  The problem alluded to in the tutorial is that the derivative expression `-Sqrt[y[x]^3]` (or equivalently `y[x]^(3/2)`) is discontinuous in a complex neighborhood of `y[0] == -2`.  The discontinuity arises from the branch-cut choice in *Mathematica*.  As for `NDSolve`, it fails to complete a solution because it tries to reduce the step size until the change in the derivative is small. That is not possible at the discontinuity.

**Analysis of phase space**

One can see the large jump in the imaginary values below:

```
-Sqrt[{-2. + 1.*^-6 I,   -2.,   -2. - 1.*^-6 I}^3]
(*  {-2.12132*10^-6 - 2.82843 I,   0. - 2.82843 I,   -2.12132*10^-6 + 2.82843 I}  *)
```

One can also see the discontinuity in the complex phase space of the differential equation:

```
StreamPlot[
 Through[{Re, Im}[-Sqrt[(yRe + yIm I)^3]]], {yRe, -2, 2}, {yIm, -2, 2},
 StreamColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][
     Rescale[ArcTan[-#3, #4], {-Pi/2, Pi/2}]] &),
 StreamColorFunctionScaling -> False, FrameLabel -> {Re[y], Im[y]}, 
 Axes -> True]

VectorPlot[
 Through[{Re, Im}[-Sqrt[(yRe + yIm I)^3]]], {yRe, -2.1, -1.9}, {yIm, -0.1, 0.1},
 VectorColorFunction -> (ColorData["Rainbow"][#4] &),
 VectorScale -> {0.7/15, 1, Automatic}, FrameLabel -> {Re[y], Im[y]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In other words there is no solution (in the ordinary sense).

**Sliding mode fails**

One might attempt a [sliding mode](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveWhenEvents.html#1688891301) solution, but `NDSolve` balks at starting at the discontinuity.  In any case the sliding solution would be the constant function `y -> (2 &)`.

**Fixed-step "solutions"**

One can force a solution by using a fixed-step method.  This will force a step using whatever value of `-Sqrt[y[x]^3]` for `y'[x]`.  The result is a "solution" that bounces back and forth across the real axis, while the real part drifts at rate that depends on the step size.  In other words, it does not produce a good solution.

```
{sol} = NDSolve[{Derivative[1][y][x] == -Sqrt[y[x]^3], y[0] == -2 + 0. I},
  y, {x, 1}, StartingStepSize -> 1/1000, 
  Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitEuler"}];

GraphicsRow[{
  Plot[Re[y[x]] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}],
  Plot[Im[y[x]] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Addendum - Determining the pathological branch**

We can mimic the behavior of `NDSolve` in solving each branch:

```
branches = Solve[{y'[x]^2 - y[x]^3 == 0, y[0]^2 == 4}, {y'[x], y[0]}] /. Rule -> Equal
(*
{{Derivative[1][y][x] == -y[x]^(3/2),  y[0] == -2},
 {Derivative[1][y][x] == -y[x]^(3/2),  y[0] ==  2},
 {Derivative[1][y][x] ==  y[x]^(3/2),  y[0] == -2},
 {Derivative[1][y][x] ==  y[x]^(3/2),  y[0] ==  2}}
*)

NDSolve[#, y, {x, 1}] & /@ branches
```

> NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 133890 steps reached at the point `` x == 1.1953773059956123`*^-7 ``. >>

Examining the output shows that the third solution in `branches` is the only one that stopped integration at `` x == 1.1953773059956123`*^-7 ``.
Note that locally at the initial condition `y[0] == -2`, the RHS of the differential equation `y[x]^(3/2)` is equal to `-Sqrt[y[x]^3]` and the IVP is in fact equivalent to the OP's IVP.

Comment: Hi,@Michael E2. Thanks very much for your detailed answer although you have missed the minus sign on the RHS of my original equation! I thinks I need some time to read and study your answer :)

Comment: @lxy I don't think I missed a minus sign: `y[x]^(3/2) == -Sqrt[y[x]^3]` when `y[x] < 0` as specified in your initial condition, which I mentioned at the beginning of my answer.  I'm not sure what other minus sign you might mean -- is there another?

Comment: But by this replacement, you might restrict the real part of the solution to be negative. I mean y[x] may be negative or positive thus your substitution is not equivalent to the original equation.

Comment: @lxy Fixed a different error (phase portrait plot) and changed the powers to Sqrt.  The power doesn't really matter since if the initial condition is a negative real number, there is no solution, so `y[x]` doesn't exist -- it can't become positive or anything else.  Another way to look at it is that according to the phase portrait, if the real part of `y[x]` is negative, then the real part is decreasing.